# Обновление данных в mysql бд

Tags: python, mysql

Возник вопрос, допустим в базе данных имеется значение 1, и это значение использует чат-бот вк, я взял и командой через чат-бота изменил данное значение. в phpmyadmin при обновлении страницы, значение поменялось, но бот продолжает использовать значение равное 1, а не изменённое. хотя .commit() применял. использование нового значения можно достигнуть, если бота перезапустить полностью. можно ли как-то это исправить? чтобы значение изменялось и при следующем запросе к данному значению, оно было уже изменённое

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если бот прочитал, запомнил, и теперь пользуется тем, что запомнил - ничего ты не сделаешь, только рестарт.

Comment: Значит вам надо сделать в боте перечитывание значения из базы при каждом запросе

Comment: @Mike такой способ и был выбран для дальнейшей разработки. Спасибо всем за помощь!